# VirtualHosts configuration in one file or not?

Tags: apache, debian, virtual-hosts

I'm running a http server on Debian (Apache 2) with one IP address. I have few domains and SVN running on the server as well. At the moment I have configuration that points my domains to the correct folders on my server with VirtualHosts.

I have done all my VirtualHosts configurations only in the file called "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default". Is this the correct way to do it, or should I make a new file for every website I'm running on my server?

At this moment, my VirtuaHosts file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default) looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain1.com
        ServerAlias domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName svn.myhostname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/svn
     <Directory /var/svn/>
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             allow from all
     </Directory>
     <Location />
             DAV svn                              
             SVNParentPath /var/svn               
             AuthType Basic                         
             AuthName "Subversion"                  
             AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-auth  
             Require valid-user                    
     </Location>
     LogLevel warn                              
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/svn.error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/svn.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'correct' way. You could also make an extra file for every Vhost. I for example have all my VHosts in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and included it via `Include httpd.conf` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

But if you want it to be a bit structured you CAN use the Apache2 built in VHosts System in `/etc/apache/sites-availible/` with multiple files for every site (VHost).

If you want you could use `nano /etc/apache2/sites-availible/mypage1` and then activate or deactivete it via the `a2ensite` command. Like `a2ensite mypage1`.